# angular controller and http variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular service that uses $http to get a json file.

```
App.factory('jsonFile', function($http) {
    var promise;
    var jsondata = {
        get: function() {
            if ( !promise ) {
                var promise =  $http.get('src/app_preprocess/data_json.js').success(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
                return promise;
            }
        }
    };
    return jsondata;
});
```

And a controller

```
App.controller('firstCtrl', function (jsonFile , $scope) {
    jsonFile.get().then(function(d) {
        $scope.header = d.data.PACKAGE.ITEM[0] 
    })
});
```

This works well.

My question is why can I not add the outcome of the http to a variable instead of the scope like so...?

```
App.controller('firstCtrl', function (jsonFile , $scope) {
    var output;
    output = jsonFile.get().then(function(d) {
        return d.data.PACKAGE.ITEM
    });
    $scope.header = output[0];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because jsonFile returns a promise and you try to use output before it returns.. only inside the `then` clause you can be assured the promise would return in the expected timing. outside of it - you can't now due to the async nature of http calls.

You can read more about promises in angular [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q)

Comment: Thanks that makes perfect sense